# Как работать с БД Oracle из MS Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, база-данных, oracle

Помогите пожалуйста! Необходимо подключиться и работать с БД oracle из MS Visual 2015  на языке с++. Не могу найти точную информацию. Везде пишут про ODT.NET, но конкретного примера я так и не увидел. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html уже пробовали?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добрый день! Вы не могли бы более подробно описать алгоритм подключения через OCCI. Помимо того что нужно скачать с сайта oracle клиент и OCCI. Как необходимо действовать дальше? Поделитесь опытом с начинающими)

Comment: Чтение документации поможет вам задавать более конкретные вопросы.